# How to compare the elements inside of the array, which is an instance of a class then storing them in another array in another class

Tags: java, arrays

Hi guys i'm trying to learn how OOP works and i just get a bit confused how my program's working

so my program is asking to input attributes like *price* and *material* to a "part" class then storing them in an array called "Part_Array" then i tried playing with inheritance and inherited a "SRC" class from the "part" class.

then what i plan to do is in another class called " SortedArray" i'm going to loop through the elements of the "partArray" class and determine if the "SRC" is compatible with a certain element of the "part_Array" class.

and if the element is compatible it's going to store the "compatible" parts onto a different array in a different class

i tried doing a SortedArray Class but the logic is just messing me up.

i'm going to add a lot more conditions to it i'm just building like the basic outline of the process.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class part {

    private String name; // a private string attribute of the name of the class
    private int price; //  a private integer attribute of the price of the part class
    private String make; // a private attribute of the material of the class
    private boolean recommended=false; // a private boolean attribute that makes the part class either recommended true or false 
    
    
    public part(String name, int price , String material){ // satisfying the CONSTRUCTOR method requirement
        
        this.name=name;
        this.make=material;
        this.price=price; 
        
    }
    
    public void recommended() {
        
         setRecommended(true);
        
    }
    
    
    public String getMaterial() { // method 2 gets the material of the part class
        
        return make; 
    }
        
    public int getPrice() {// method 3 gets the price of the part class
        
        return price;
    }
                
    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
        String FormattedPrice = decimalFormat.format(price);
        return  "Part Name: " + name +"\n"+ "Price: " + FormattedPrice +"\n"+ "Part is made of: " + make+ "\n"; 
        
        
    }

    public boolean isRecommended() {
        return recommended;
    }

    public boolean setRecommended(boolean recommended) {
        this.recommended = recommended;
        return recommended;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class Part_Array {
      private part[] parts; // Array to store part objects
        private int numberOfParts;// Counter to keep track of the number of parts
                
        public Part_Array() {
            parts = new part[100]; // Initialize the array with a size of 100
            numberOfParts = 0;// Initialize the counter to 0   
            
        }       
        // Method to add a new part to the array
        public void addPart(part newPart) {
            if (numberOfParts < 100) {
                parts[numberOfParts] = newPart;
                numberOfParts++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Cannot add more parts. The array is full.");
            }
        }

        // Method to retrieve a part by its index in the array
        public part getPart(int index) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < numberOfParts) {
                return parts[index];
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid index.");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Method to get the total number of parts in the array
        public int getAllParts() {
            return numberOfParts;
        }
        public void PrintList() {
            for (int i = 0; i < getAllParts(); i++) {
                System.out.println(parts[i].toString());
                
            }
        }
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

public class SortedArray {
    public void sort(){
        Part_Array rcmd = new Part_Array();
        Part_Array other = new Part_Array();

        for (int i = 0; i < manager.getAllParts(); i++) {
            part retrievedPart = manager.getPart(i);
            if (retrievedPart != null) {
                if (retrievedPart.getPrice() < srcInstance.getPrice()) {
                    retrievedPart.recommended();
                    rcmd.addPart(retrievedPart);
                } else {
                    other.addPart(retrievedPart);
                }
            }
        }

        
    }

    public void printRecommendedParts(List<part> rcmdList) {
        System.out.println("Recommended Parts:");
        for (part p : rcmdList) {
            if (p.isRecommended()) {
                System.out.println(p.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the SRC class that i intend to build an object from to serve as the basis of comparison for the elements inside the "part_Array" Class

```
public class SRC extends part {

    public SRC(String name, int price, String material) {
        super(name, price, material);   
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.